# Android application(.apk files) updating for an existing app in Google play

Tags: android

At present I am having four `.apk` files for an android application with different version code and version 1.0 . Now I want to update my app with same four `.apk` files but there are now some changes in the manifest file for each apk. I a using same certificate key(existing one) and different version code with 1.1 version for each updated `.apk` file.

Now in my Google play account for that app, existing four apk are there in active mode. Now when I will upload my updated four apks, I have to activate them too.

My question is wether I should deactivate the older ones or leave them as it is ?

**Previously used:**

```
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

**Currently using:**

```
 android:minSdkVersion="8"
 android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

Comment: Why do you need to deactivate them? Just publish the updated APK's. I don't quite understand the question anyway.

Comment: Hi I am new to Android development, so was confused by the fact that already there are four apks(existing one) with version 1.0. If now I am again uploading four updated apks, then total there will be 8 apks. Again in future if I update my app, it will increase by 4. So maximum how many apks we can upload for one app.

Comment: The 4 new 1.1 version APK's that you will upload as _updates_ will replace the old 1.0 version APK's. You do not have to un-publish the old APK's. Google play will simply replace them with updated APK's

Comment: Warning: Multiple active APKs support some of the same devices. If a device is supported by more than one APK, it will receive the one with the higher version. I got this message after uploading 4 more apks. Is it OK....